# Spring Boot / MVC - failover action

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a spring boot/mvc application running and I would like to have a method which would be called when URL isn't resolved(like 404) and which could access original request (requestPath, data, etc.).

I thought I could use custom NOT_FOUND action like this:

***SpringConfiguration***

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
            container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/404"));
        }
    };
}
```

***Controller***

```
@RequestMapping("/404")
public Response<?> notFound(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // ...
}
```

This works but the problem is that in the **notFound** method **request** doesn't contain the original request info.

Could you please advice?